# function to find the longest increasing subsequence without arrays

Tags: c

I need to make a program in C with those instructions:
the problem is its kinda easy to do with arrays but without them,I cant think anything else.

**we need to write a function that takes int n and then takes the sequences of numbers, the function need to return us the sum of the biggest sequence.**
for `n = 8  and the sequence = 2,4,6,8,11,14,17,9' (there is 2 long sequences of 4, (when 8 starts the new sequence and closes the current sequence)` here we will get the print 50.`

for n = 2 and the sequence 7,19 the function will print 26.
for n = 8 and the sequence **8,6,4,2**,11,14,15,16
the longest length is 4 so the function will print 20.

can't find any solution here without arrays

```
 printf("please choose a n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    y = n;
    if (n == 1)
  {
        printf("Please enter the next number ");
        scanf("%d", &series);
        return series;
    }
  else
    if (n == 2)
  {
        while (i < 2) {
    {
        printf("Please enter the next number ");
            scanf("%d", &series);
            sum += series;
        }
        return sum;
    }
   printf("Plase choose another number");
scanf("%d", &last);
sum += last;
printf("please choose another number");
scanf("%d", &series);
d = series - last;
sum = series + last;
bSum = sum;
for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
    last = series;
    printf("Please write another number; ");
    scanf("%d", &series);
     if (series - last == d)
      {
          sum += series;
          count++;
      }
      if (series - last != d)
      {
          if (count > length)
          {
              bSum = sum;
              length = count;
          }
          else if (count == length && sum > bSum)
          {
              bSum = sum;
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an assignment question?   You only need to remember the `start`, `end` and `length` of any sequence.  So when you find a sequence remember it into a `previous_seq` or suchlike.  Then if a new sequence is found, if it's bigger, replace the stored one.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question which was almost identical?

Comment: @chqrlie i got such a big headache while trying to edit it so i made a new one, sorry about that.

Comment: "when 8 starts the new sequence and closes the current sequence" -->  11 closed the prior sequence and established the new 8, 11, ... sequence.

Comment: @Kingsley but what about n? its determined when its stop

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well thats i how got the assignment

Comment: What do you mean by "biggest sequence"? The longest running? The sum is maximal? If you have negatives, can you cut the sequence early? Weakly increasing of strongly increasing? What if the longest sequence is not the highest sum?

Comment: What is `n`? I assumed it was the number of values in the rest of the file. But, for your first example, you have: `n = 8  and the sequence = 2,4,6,8,11,14,17` AFAICT, there are only 7 numbers and _not_ 8. And, there is only _one_ sequence of length 7 and the sum is 62. So, how do you get _two_ sequences as the numbers only increase? If you mean `2,4,6,8` has a difference of 2 but `11,14,17` has a difference of 3, then you need to edit your _question_ and make this [absolutely ;-)] clear.

Comment: Re “… the sequence 8,6,4,2,11,14,15,16 the longest length is 4 so the function will print 20”: What? 20 is the sum of 8+6+4+2, but those are not an increasing sequence. The longest increasing sequence there is 2, 11, 14, 15, 16, which has a sum of 58. Edit the question to fix the mistakes and ambiguities. Clearly define what an “increasing subsequence” is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  its probably a bad type and its just increasing. from 2 to 8 till 16,
8 starts and finished the new sequence. so 8 closes the first sequence and starts a new one after

Comment: @CraigEsty you're right
I forgot to add 9 after 17
so the correct sequence is 2,4,6,8,11,14,17,9

Comment: @Neil the biggest sequence is the one with the most length of numbers, only if both sequences have same length only then we check which has the bigger sum and we print it, its its the longest alone so just printing the sum of it

Comment: So `[1,2,3,4,5,4,5000]` would print 15 and not 5004? I believe you will need to track the value and size. (It's not an optimization problem.) What about `[-2,-1,1,2]`, can we choose what numbers, 3, or is it 0? What about `[1,1,1,1,1]`, 5 or 1?

Comment: @Neil but what about the n? which is the length of the sequence.
if n = 7 and for the list [1,2,3,4,5,4,5000] the sum will be 15.
[-2,-1,1,2] n = 4 and the sum is 3 (if length is equal so we print the bigger sum,
[1,1,1,1,1] that's actually tricky but i think its will print 1 because 1 -1 = 0 and as far as i remember a sequence can't go with 0 (n^0)
i hope it answer all the questions

Comment: For 10k users: this question was asked yesterday, too, as the now deleted [How to find the longest increasing subsequence without arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74533516/how-to-find-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-without-arrays). A lot of advice was given.  The old question includes the same problematic "n = 8; data = 2,4,6,8,11,14,17" example which has only 7 elements in the data and they are in a monotonically increasing sequence of 7 values.

Comment: So a high-level description of "biggest" is given a sequence of integers, break it into strictly increasing subsequences, (which you can do unambiguously). Of the largest cardinality subsequences, pick one (there could be many) that has the largest sum of all positive integers in the subsequence, and print that number?

Answer (score 2):

I had coded this up, but needed clarification from OP (see my top comments).

As a result ...

I added code to pick a sequence of equal length to the best but with a larger sum.

Because it was minimal changes to my code, I chose that the longest sequence wins:

1. For input of `-2 -1 1 2`, this is a sequence of 4 with sum 0. It is *not* two sequences of 2 `-2 -1` and `1 2` with sum 3.
2. For input of `1 1 1 1 1`, this is a sequence of 5 with sum 5 and *not* 5 sequences of 1 [each] with sum 1

---

Here is the code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{

    // get count of sequence numbers
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // length of current sequence
    int curlen = 0;

    // sum of current sequence
    int cursum = 0;

    // value of current number
    int curval;

    // value of previous number
    int oldval;

    // get the first number
    scanf("%d",&oldval);

    // add it to the current sequence
    curlen += 1;
    cursum += oldval;

    // initialize the best sequence from the current one
    int bestsum = cursum;
    int bestlen = curlen;

    // get all remaining numbers in the sequence
    for (int i = 1;  i < n;  ++i, oldval = curval) {
        // get new current number
        if (scanf("%d",&curval) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"too short\n");
            break;
        }

        // reset the current sequence if we're not increasing
        if (curval < oldval) {
            cursum = 0;
            curlen = 0;
        }

        // add to the current sequence
        cursum += curval;
        curlen += 1;

        // save off the longest sequence we've seen
        if (curlen > bestlen) {
            bestlen = curlen;
            bestsum = cursum;
            continue;
        }

        // save off a sequence that is the same length as the best but has a
        // larger sum
        if ((curlen == bestlen) && (cursum > bestsum)) {
            bestsum = cursum;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // print the final/best sum
    printf("%d\n",bestsum);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Input:

```
4
-2 -1 1 2
```

Output: 0

---

Input:

```
5
1 1 1 1 1
```

Output: 5

---

Input:

```
2
7 19
```

Output: 26

---

Input:

```
8
2 4 6 8 11 14 17 9
```

Output: 62

---

Input:

```
8
8 6 4 2 11 14 15 16
```

Output: 58

---

Input:

```
12
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

Output: 18

---

Input:

```
2
2 1
```

Output: 2

---

Here is the `perl` script that I used to generate the tests:

**Edit:** Updated for example below.

````
#!/usr/bin/perl
# runseq -- run sequence program
#
# options:
#   "-D" -- cc -D options
#   "-S<sfile>" -- source file (DEFAULT: seq.c)
#   "-clip" -- send output to xclip program
#   "-d" -- debug runseq script
#
# arguments:
#   1-- [optional] comma separated list of sequence numbers (e.g. 3,7 2,1)

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    optdcd(\@argv,
        "+opt_D","opt_S","opt_clip");

    # get source file
    $sroot = $opt_S;
    $sroot //= "seq";
    $sroot =~ s/[.].+$//;

    zprtx("compiling %s ...\n",$sroot);
    $sfile = "$sroot.c";
    sysfault("runseq: no source file\n")
        unless (-e $sfile);

    push(@cc,"cc");
    push(@cc,"-o$sroot");
    foreach $opt (@opt_D) {
        push(@cc,"-D$opt");
    }
    push(@cc,$sfile);

    $cmd = join(" ",@cc);
    zprtx("%s\n",$cmd);

    $code = vxsystem(@cc);
    exit(1) if ($code);

    $tmpfile = "inp.txt";

    # send to xclip program
    if ($opt_clip) {
        open($xfout,"|xclip");
    }
    else {
        $xfout = \*STDOUT;
    }

    {
        # take tests from command line
        if (@argv > 0) {
            foreach $arg (@argv) {
                $arg =~ s/,/ /g;
                @body = ($arg);
                dosum();
            }
            last;
        }

        # get test data from below
        $xfdata = \*seq::DATA;
        while ($dat = <$xfdata>) {
            chomp($dat);

            # ignore comments
            next if ($dat =~ /^\s*#/);

            # blank line separates tests
            if ($dat =~ /^\s*$/) {
                dosum();
                next;
            }

            push(@body,$dat);
        }
    }

    # do final test
    dosum()
        if (@body > 0);

    close($xfout)
        if ($opt_clip);
}

# optdcd -- decode command line options
sub optdcd
{
    my(@syms) = @_;
    my($argv);
    my($arg);
    my($ary);
    my($symlhs,$symrhs,$val,$match);

    $argv = shift(@syms);

    # get options
    while (@$argv > 0) {
        $arg = $argv->[0];
        last unless ($arg =~ /^-/);

        shift(@$argv);

        $match = 0;
        foreach $symrhs (@syms) {
            $symlhs = $symrhs;
            $ary = ($symlhs =~ s/^[+]//);

            $opt = $symlhs;
            $opt =~ s/^opt_/-/;

            zprt("optdcd: TRYARG arg='%s' symrhs='%s' symlhs='%s' opt='%s' ary=%d\n",
                $arg,$symrhs,$symlhs,$opt,$ary);

            if ($arg =~ /^$opt(.*)$/) {
                $val = $1;

                $val =~ s/^=//;
                $val = 1
                    if ($val eq "");

                if ($ary) {
                    zprt("optdcd: PUSH val=%s\n",$val);
                    push(@$symlhs,$val);
                }
                else {
                    zprt("optdcd: SET val=%s\n",$val);
                    $$symlhs = $val;
                }

                $match = 1;
                last;
            }
        }

        sysfault("optdcd: unknown option -- '%s'\n",$arg)
            unless ($match);
    }
}

sub dosum
{
    my($bf);
    my(@rhs);
    my(@n);

    zprtx("\n")
        if ($opt_clip);

    $xfdst = xfopen(">$tmpfile","dosum");

    # get count of sequence values (i.e. "n")
    foreach $bf (@body) {
        @rhs = split(" ",$bf);
        push(@n,@rhs);
    }
    printf($xfdst "%d\n",scalar(@n));

    foreach $bf (@body) {
        zprtx("dosum: %s\n",$bf)
            if ($opt_clip);
        print($xfdst $bf,"\n");
    }
    $xfdst = xfclose($xfdst);

    # run program
    my($outval) = (`./$sroot < $tmpfile`);
    chomp($outval);

    # output test input data and program output
    outf("\n");
    outf("----------\n")
        if ($opt_clip);
    outf("Input:\n");
    outf("```\n")
        if ($opt_clip);
    $xfsrc = xfopen("<$tmpfile","dosum");
    while ($buf = <$xfsrc>) {
        outf("%s",$buf);
    }
    $xfsrc = xfclose($xfsrc);
    outf("```\n")
        if ($opt_clip);

    outf("\n")
        if ($opt_clip);
    outf("Output: %d\n",$outval);

    undef(@body);
}

sub outf
{

    printf($xfout @_);
}

sub zprt
{

    goto &zprtx
        if ($opt_d);
}

sub zprtx
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
}

sub sysfault
{

    zprtx(@_);
    exit(1);
}

sub xfopen
{
    my($file,$who) = @_;
    my($xf);

    open($xf,$file) or
        sysfault("xfopen: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$file);

    $xf;
}

sub xfclose
{
    my($xf) = @_;

    close($xf);

    undef($xf);

    $xf;
}

sub vxsystem
{
    my($cmd);

    $cmd = join(" ",@_);

    system($cmd);

    $? >> 8;
}

package seq;
__DATA__
-2 -1 1 2

1 1 1 1 1

7 19

2 4 6 8 11 14 17 9

8 6 4 2 11 14 15 16

1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6

2 1
````

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a version that adds some debug printing (-DDEBUG). And, selection of `<=` vs `<` (-DLE).

I've updated the `runseq` script above to handle this version [it is backwards compatible].

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    fprintf(stderr,_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

int
main(void)
{

    // get count of sequence numbers
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    // length of current sequence
    int curlen = 0;

    // sum of current sequence
    int cursum = 0;

    // value of current number
    int curval;

    // value of previous number
    int oldval = 0;

    // get the first number
    scanf("%d", &curval);

    // add it to the current sequence
    curlen += 1;
    cursum += curval;

    dbgprt("OLD: oldval=%d curval=%d cursum=%d curlen=%d\n",
        oldval,curval,cursum,curlen);

    oldval = curval;

    // initialize the best sequence from the current one
    int bestsum = cursum;
    int bestlen = curlen;

    // get all remaining numbers in the sequence
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i, oldval = curval) {
        // get new current number
        if (scanf("%d", &curval) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "too short\n");
            break;
        }

        // reset the current sequence if we're not increasing
#if LE
        if (curval <= oldval) {
            cursum = 0;
            curlen = 0;
            dbgprt("ZAPLE\n");
        }
#else
        if (curval < oldval) {
            cursum = 0;
            curlen = 0;
            dbgprt("ZAPLT\n");
        }
#endif

        // add to the current sequence
        cursum += curval;
        curlen += 1;

        dbgprt("CUR: oldval=%d curval=%d cursum=%d curlen=%d\n",
            oldval,curval,cursum,curlen);

        // save off the longest sequence we've seen
        if (curlen > bestlen) {
            dbgprt("NEWLEN\n");
            bestlen = curlen;
            bestsum = cursum;
            continue;
        }

        // save off a sequence that is the same length as the best but has a
        // larger sum
        if ((curlen == bestlen) && (cursum > bestsum)) {
            dbgprt("NEWSUM\n");
            bestsum = cursum;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // print the final/best sum
    printf("%d\n", bestsum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I actually was pretty close but took the long run haha
i am just having trouble to understand the if scanf != 1 , does it means that if n is not equal to 1 print to short? am i just reading it wrong?

Comment: @GuyGuy The `scanf` return value is the number of fields it matched. Loosely, that is, the number of '%` that matched. So, for `scanf("%d",&curval)` it will return 1 if a number could be decoded or 0 if the input wasn't a number (or it got EOF). From `man scanf`: _On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure._

Comment: I think this is what OP meant by, "can't find any solution here without arrays"; _viz_, an _on-line_ algorithm that requires `O(1)` space.

Comment: @CraigEstey sorry for late comment i actually wanted to understand it and re write it but i dont a bit confused when i tried ur code and i used n = 8 and sequence of 2,4,6,8,11,14,17,9 is printing 62 when its should just print 50 ( its adding the first 3 numbers to the sum) is it just to add and if argument for the sum? or for the d (n2 - n1)?

Comment: @GuyGuy _Side note:_ The `n` at the front really isn't necessary if we just monitor the return value of `scanf` [as I did]. If it's _required_ in the input, so be it. But, for `n==8` and `2,4,6,8,11,14,17,9` there are just _two_ increasing sequences: `2,4,6,8,11,14,17` and `9`. So, 62 is correct. There's nothing in the original question [plus comments] to indicate how `3` factors in at all!? Where did `3` come from? Is this some part of a requirement that was never posted? _I'm_ confused ;-)

Comment: @CraigEstey
you're totally right the proffesor told us that he had a bad type, which was kinda stupid but he still wants it his way, but i already thought about a way to fix it, just to add a if with checking curval - oldval is equal to another one.

Comment: he didnt give us any factors just an examples and we need to figure it out

Comment: @GuyGuy If you wanted (e.g.) `1,1,1,1,1` to sum to 1 and _not_ 5, then, yes, change `if (curval < oldval)` into `if (curval <= oldval)`. I had been thinking about adding an update to mention this, but decided I had done enough "interpolation" of the problem statement ;-)

Comment: @GuyGuy  It might have helped to do a full copy-and-paste of the original assignment text. Then, we would have been able to decide if the problem statement was complete and unambiguous. We [here on SO] are perfectly willing to call instructors idiots [if they pose bad/incomplete assignments or _require_ you to use bad coding techniques] :-)

Comment: @CraigEstey The Problem its not entirely english i didnt want to confuse you so i tried to translate it as best as i could with the examples which are just numbers so ye)
and changing curval <= oldval didnt change a thing for the result i still get 62.

Comment: @GuyGuy I just tested the change I/you suggested and for `1,1,1,1,1`, I now get 1 and _not_ 5. I'm confused [again] ;-)

Comment: well then you changed more things :)
If you only changed the if by addding = nothign changes
try the list that i did 2,4,6,8,11,14,17,9 the answer here should be 50( but its still 62)
and i copy your exact code and try n = 5 with 1 1 1 1 1 i will not get anything printed

Comment: @CraigEstey
https://imgur.com/a/EM8BHrp

Comment: @GuyGuy No, for `2,4,6,8,11,14,17,9` the correct answer _is_ 62 and _not_ 50. `2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 11 + 14 + 17` --> `62` Why do you say 50? Again, no, my posted version is/was the latest. I've downloaded it and reverified it. The `<` --> `<=` _does_ produce 1 for `1 1 1 1 1` I've updated my answer to add a version with some debugging. Your image shows an `n` of 5 but 6 lines afterwards. But, this still works correctly.